# How to translate this expr from pinescript v2 to v5

Tags: pine-script-v5

I´m trying to recode expr to Pinescript v5 but doesn't work same way, any idea?

Pinescript v2:

MA2 = nz(MA2[1]) + smooth * (hlc3 - nz(MA2[1]))

Pinescript v5:

float nAMA = 0.

MA := nz(MA[1]) + smooth * (hlc3 - nz(MA[1]))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

`float nAMA = 0.`

By

`float MA = 0.`